# mysql silent install and configure in nsi

Tags: mysql, silent-install, nsis

I want to silently install MySQL 5.0 in NSI. I tried the following code in NSI:

```
  ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\mysql-essential-5.0.27-win32.msi" /qn'
  ExecWait "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=root ServerType=DEVELOPMENT    DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 RootCurrentPassword=root"
```

This installs the MySQL but doesn't cofigure it.

I want to configure it with

- pass=root
- port=3306
- servicename=Mysql
- and enable root access from remote machine

**EDIT1**

Now it's getting configured...

For serverhost as localhost or 127.0.0.1 it works, but not for the ip addreses of the other systems .which are on network.

If I try to access the database on silently installed database from PC on network I get the following error:

[image]

I think this is because I need to pass some parameter for and enabling  root access from remote machine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quoting the `mysqlinstanceconfig.exe` filename, like this:

```
ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\mysql-essential-5.0.27-win32.msi" /qn'
ExecWait "$\"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe$\" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=root ServerType=DEVELOPMENT    DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 RootCurrentPassword=root"
```

The reason for this is that you have spaces in the path to the executable name. That path must be surrounded with quotes so it can form a single path.

Comment: it still not getting configured...:(..
is the configuring code correct?

Comment: I have only ran the two commands you specified, and MySQL Query browser is working for me. It can connect locally to the database.

Comment: i want to connect it remotely..
how to do that..
i have edited my question..

Comment: Try adding `SkipNetworking=no` in the commandline for mysqlinstanceconfig. You can see all the parameters [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-cmdline.html)

Comment: do i have to add SkipNetworking=no at end of Execwait line ?
 ExecWait "$\"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe$\" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=root ServerType=DEVELOPMENT    DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 RootCurrentPassword=root  SkipNetworking=no"   

then not working..(

Comment: Try restarting the MySQL service after you have configured it. If not even that works, I'm afraid I can't help you further since I don't have 2 networked computers to test on.

Answer (score 0):

The whole command passed to `ExecWait` should be enclosed in `''` if it contains spaces.

The parameters **inside** your parameters, need to be enclosed in `""` if they contain spaces.
You can see a perfect example of how to do it **correctly** in your first call to `ExecWait`.

> Note, if the command could have spaces, you should put it in quotes to delimit it from parameters. e.g.: ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\command.exe" parameters'.

Source: [Documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.4)